# Popular dados PHP

Tags: banco-de-dados, ajax

Ola, por favor quero saber quais procedimentos utilizo para popular dados em um simples campo de um formulário usando Ajax.

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/ajax-com-jquery-trabalhando-com-requisicoes-assincronas/37141 Nesse site ele explica melhor pra voce como fazer essas requisicoes, e o melhor em php como voce quer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja preencher os campos de um formulário com dados vindos do PHP através de uma requisição ajax, imaginando que você tenha um formulário como:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input name="campo1" type="text">
    <input name="campo2" type="text">
    <button type="button">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Você pode usar algo no front-end js como:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    buscaDadosFormulario();
});

function buscaDadosFormulario() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://seusite.com.br/seumetodo",
        data: {
            //send filter data here as json format
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            $('input[name=campo1]').val(response.valor1);
            $('input[name=campo2]').val(response.valor2);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('Falha ao buscar dados');
        }
    });
}
```

Seu retorno do back-end (PHP) será algo como:

```
//Simulando dados retornados do banco de dados ou de qualquer rotina
$dbData = [
    'valor1' => 'Teste do campo 1',
    'valor2' => 'Teste do campo 2'
];

echo json_encode($dbData);
```

Agora, se sua necessidade é registrar os dados de um formulário no banco através do PHP, recebendo dados de um formulário no front-end através de ajax, você pode fazer algo como:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input name="campo1" type="text">
    <input name="campo2" type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="registrarDados()">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

No javascript:

```
function registrarDados() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://seusite.com.br/seumetodo",
        data: {
            valor1: $('input[name=campo1]').val(),
            valor2: $('input[name=campo2]').val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            //do something...
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('Falha ao buscar dados');
        }
    });
}
```

No lado do PHP você poderá resgatar os dados do ajax pela superglobal POST em forma de array:

```
echo 'valor1 é igual a ' . $_POST['valor1'];
echo 'valor2 é igual a ' . $_POST['valor2'];
```

Para saber como conectar a um banco mysql com PHP você pode seguir este tutorial: https://serprogramador.com.br/artigos/topico/php/aprenda-como-conectar-a-um-banco-de-dados-MySql-usando-PHP-atraves-da-funcao-mysqli

Espero que eu tenha sido útil! =D